# Disable windows security popup

Tags: c#, uwp, sap-smp

I am developing Sap Mobile Platform application in windows UWP.

While registering the application with the server, windows opens a self defined popup for username and password (If the given credentials fails). How to to disable the popup.

Comment: What would you like to happen instead for invalid credentials? Also code showing the registration would help. Update the question with it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain
Just we have to disable the popup. If the credentials are wrong the sdk throws exception that is handled by showing message to enter proper credentials. Based on the response from the server(if success) we are storing the encrypted credentials on the device for future offline login.  If the user feeds the correct credentials on the popup, the code cannot get the credentials. So we just need to disable it.

Comment: @Elad is asking any updates? looking for the same solution...